# Use CPU if GPU not present

Tags: python, tensorflow

self.device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

The code to check if there is a gpu or not, and if there isn't, to utilise the cpu, is described above, using Pytorch.
How to implement this using tensorflow?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have all the necessary libraries installed (drivers, CUDA, etc.), Tensorflow will automatically run on the GPU, no changes required. You can use the following code to check if Tensorflow recognizes your GPU:

```
import tensorflow as tf

gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    print("Name:", gpu.name, "  Type:", gpu.device_type)
```

If there is no GPU available this code will simply print out nothing, so you know, that Tensorflow did not find a GPU to run your model on. In that case, Tensorflow will run normally on the CPU. There is no explicit code necessary to switch between GPU and CPU.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I wanted to know the code to check for the availability of a GPU , if GPU is not present the use CPU.